# How to query mongo in php?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

So I've got this simple login function that is trying to match email address with a password in the database and compare it with the user entered data via form.

```
function login($email, $password){
    $m = new Mongo("localhost"); 
    $m->connect();
    $db = $m->users;
    $collection = $db->test_collection;

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($collection->findOne(array('name' => 'john'))); //returns correctly
    var_dump($collection->find(array('name' => 'john'))); //returns mongo cursor object
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

I don't understand why the find() only returns a cursor object. Answers?

This is the mongo document

```
array(5) {
  ["_id"]=>
  object(MongoId)#22 (1) {
    ["$id"]=>"4d7eaa848baf84d32b000000"
  }
  ["activated"]=> (true)
  ["email"]=> "john@smith.com"
  ["name"]=> "john"
  ["password"]=> "334c4a4c42fdb79d7ebc3e73b517e6f8"
}
```

How would I do a "WHERE" query that would find both email and password in the same document? I'm obviously not getting the paramaters correct for the find() and findOne() queries. What is the correct syntax in PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find` is supposed to return a cursor - you can read more about them here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Queries+and+Cursors . 
To get the documents from the cursor, you will have to iterate over it.

In your case, `findOne` is probably what you are after since you don't expect multiple users with the same username and password. The findOne function always returns at most one document, so there is no need for a cursor.

To have multiple predicates in your queries, just add more fields to your query array:

```
var_dump($collection->findOne(array('name' => 'john', 'password' => '334c4a4c42fdb79d7ebc3e73b517e6f8')));
```

(If that is correct PHP - my PHP is a bit rusty)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
return count($collection->find(array('name' => $name, 'password' => $password)));
```