# MONGODB - syntax error, unexpected '{' find method with $in operator

Tags: php, mongodb

I developed this piece of PHP code:

```
 $cursor = $collection->find
    (
        {
            username:
            {
                $in: ['admin', 'test']
            }
        }
    );
```

but this message was displayed:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'

I am using:

> targetMinOS: Windows 10  (64 bits)
>
> db version v3.6.4

According to the [MONGODB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-versus-in), this code is right.

What's wrong?

UPDATE: This question was marked as duplicate but the referenced link doesn't mention this question which is specific of my code.

> UPDATE #2 : This question was solved thanks to Neil Lunn and Deceze comments. I was wrong why I took a look to the MongoDB Shell documentation. My fault.

Comment: It's PHP and not JavaScript. Use `[]` or `array()` instead of `{}`. You also need to quote `''` your keys with PHP, and of course `=>` and not `:`. Different language to the documentation.

Comment: Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334723/how-to-query-mongo-in-php

Comment: Since I am following the notation provided by MongoDB, I consider this syntax is right. Please, click on link to verify it.

Comment: That *server* Mongo manual gives all samples in Javascript which work on the mongo console. What you want is to look specifically at your PHP driver documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/tutorial/crud/

Comment: The presumed error is located at the first '{' (line # 3 of this piece of code)